# $|\mathbb{N}|\neq|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ by using the Cantor's diagonal argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A General question about a proof:

While I was reading to proof of $|\mathbb{N}|\neq|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ by using the Cantor's diagonal argument, I saw that they defined $h\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to be $h(x)=(f(x))(x)+1$ when $f : \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ but I can't understand what does $(f(x))(x)$ means?

Comment: Think about what kind of object $f$ is, and therefore what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ maps natural numbers to sequences of natural numbers, i.e. functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Therefore for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $f(x) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of natural numbers.

$(f(x))(y)$ is just the $y$-th term of that sequence.

Comment: The concept of "currying" is related here. Any $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ can be identified with another function, say $g$, mapping $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. That identification looks like $g(x,y)=(f(x))(y)$. That is, you plug $x$ into $f$ to get another function and then you plug $y$ into that new function to get a number. Here they are taking the "diagonal" of such a $g$ by taking both arguments to be the same.

Comment: It may be easier at first to replace the *function* $f$ with a *sequence* $(f_i)$ where each $f_i$ is a map $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$; then what's written above as "$(f(x))(x)$" corresponds here to "$f_x(x)$." Then note that a sequence of functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is really the same thing as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{$functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Use Cantor's diag . . . Oh wait.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x)$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.  That is, $f(x)$ is itself a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, and you can evaluate it at any element of $\mathbb{N}$.  So $(f(x))(x)$ is the function $f(x)$ evaluated at the input $x$, which gives an output in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: if for example $x=1$ then what would I get?

Comment: You get $(f(1))(1)$.  There isn't anything more concrete you can say without choosing a specific $f$.